# Strange screen artefacts on MacBook Pro 2013

Tags: macbook-pro, display

I have MacBook Pro 15" 2013 late, and I have problem with screen artefacts for longer time. It appears randomly, even tough I don't do anything with notebook. It appears and after few moments dissapears but sometimes I have to only move with mouse and all artefacts immediately dissapear.

If I have connected notebook to external display, this problem occurs only on MacBook display, external display is without this problem. I have tried almost everything reinstall, reset SMC and PRAM. My MacBook has display changed for 2 times (1. antireflective coating problem, 2. changed display has a problem with brightness), and I am affraid, that someone during repairing damaged some piece of HW. Could someone help me, where could be a problem?

[image]

[image]

Comment: While the image would suggest a GPU issue, the fact that it only occurs on the internal display and not the external one would mean the fault is with the display. If the display has been swapped recently I would suggest you go back to the place that repaired it and have them check it the connection sits properly.